urql TypeError: t.executeQuery is not a function
Assumptions

Node.js 20.14.0
Next.js 14.2.3
urql 4.1.0
@urql/core 5.0.4
@urql/next 1.1.1

Main topic
When I use Urql in the Client Component of Next.js, I get this error message.
TypeError: t.executeQuery is not a function
Please let me know the cause of this problem.
The code is as follows.
export function useGetEventByIdQuery(options: Omit<Urql.UseQueryArgs<Operations.GetEventByIdQueryVariables>, 'query'>) {
  return Urql.useQuery<Operations.GetEventByIdQuery, Operations.GetEventByIdQueryVariables>({ query: Operations.GetEventByIdDocument, . .options });
};

  const [data] = useGetEventByIdQuery({ variables: { id: params.id } }); }


API fix
lower urql version


I ran into this as well. Follow the instructions on the urql Next Documentation
Specifically, this portion where it refers to the Context & Provider.

When we aren't leveraging server components we will import the things we will need to do a bit more setup, we go to the client component's layout file and structure it as the following.

// app/client/layout.tsx
'use client';

import { useMemo } from 'react';
import { UrqlProvider, ssrExchange, cacheExchange, fetchExchange, createClient } from '@urql/next';

export default function Layout({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren) {
  const [client, ssr] = useMemo(() => {
    const ssr = ssrExchange({
      isClient: typeof window !== 'undefined',
    });
    const client = createClient({
      url: 'https://trygql.formidable.dev/graphql/web-collections',
      exchanges: [cacheExchange, ssr, fetchExchange],
      suspense: true,
    });

    return [client, ssr];
  }, []);

  return (
    <UrqlProvider client={client} ssr={ssr}>
      {children}
    </UrqlProvider>
  );
}

